# django - how to get back an empty choice in choice field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model in Django that looks like this:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

The goal is to make a form for this model with select widget for the `parent` field that will represent the hierarchical structure of projects. I tried to redefine choices pairs for this field by sorting queryset and adding indent in front of the label for each choice. But when I make a list of pairs `(project.id, project.name)` for the form

```py
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ordered = []
        // ... making ordered list ...
        self.fields['parent'].choices = ordered
```

the default empty choice for this field gets lost. Does anyone know how to get it back?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `__init__`, add:

```
self.fields['parent'].choices = ordered
self.fields['parent'].choices.append('', u'None)
```

Comment: I modified it a little bit to make the default option come first:
`self.fields['parent'].choices.insert(0, ('', u'------'))`